# Make multiple post requests at once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am building a game in which I want players to be able to add as few as two or as many as four players.  Each player has a name and a character.

The class thus far looks like this:

```
class UserForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      warnings: {},
      error: null,
      success: null,
      name: "",
      piece: "",
    };

    this.submitRequest = this.submitRequest.bind(this);
  }

  submitRequest(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var content = {
      name: this.state.name,
      piece: this.state.piece
    };

    createUser(content)
      .then(() => {
        return this.setState({
          success: "User Added!",
          error: null,
          warnings: {}
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return this.setState({
          error: err.message || "An unexpected error occurred",
          warnings: {}
        });
      });
  }

  addUser(stateName, e,playerNumber) {
    this.setState({
      [stateName]: e.target.value,
      [playerNumber]:playerNumber
    });
  }

  render() {

    var inputFields = (
      < div >
        <label>
          Name:
            <input type="text" onChange={e => this.addUser("name", e)} />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Piece:
            <input type="text" onChange={e => this.addUser("piece", e)} />
        </label>
      </div >
    );
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitRequest}>
          <label>
            Player 1
          </label>
          <br />
          {inputFields}
          Player 2
          <br />
          {inputFields}
          Player 3
          <br />
          {inputFields}
          Player 4
          <br />
          {inputFields}
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <div className="alert alert-danger mt-2" role="alert">
          {this.state.error}
          {this.state.success}
        </div>
      </div >
    );
  }
}
export default UserForm;
```

I want all the players to be added to my database when one submit button is pressed.  But the data is essentially the same in each case.  I've been fiddling around with this by using for loops, etc. for a while but it doesn't seem quite right.  Grateful for any help!
Thanks,

Comment: You're not adding any player numbers to `this.addUser("name", e)`

Comment: Not certain what the issue is with the code. Where is `fetch()` used?

Answer (score 0):

First thing

You are passing only two Parameters I.e, name, event to addUser function from input field but in addUser you are trying to access three parameters

```
 addUser(stateName, e,playerNumber) //this is wrong
 addUser(stateName, e) //this is correct
```

Then as you mentioned you want to submit all players info in one submit in this case you need three states

```
 this.state= {
 name:””,
 piece:””,
 userData: []
 }
```

So whenever addUser is called then push player information to a state array and finally send that array when form is submitted. You can iterate list of players info in the backend while constructing a query.

Also when you assign value to name and piece state you have to pass these states as a value to an input field otherwise you won’t get value

```
 <input type=“text” value={this.state.name} onChange={e => this.addUser(“name”, e)} />
```